# GAE: Upgrading vm: true to env: flex drives auto-scaler to create infinite amount of instances

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I've noticed that when I'm upgrading the vm tag to the new env one, that the auto scaler creates an infinite amount of instances during the deployment process. This only happens when I'm using the new env flag. This is my conf file:

```
runtime: custom
vm: true
service: default
threadsafe: true
health_check:
  enable_health_check: True
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  unhealthy_threshold: 2
  healthy_threshold: 2
  restart_threshold: 60
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  cool_down_period_sec: 60
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.9
```

It would be great if anyone could help me because I'm unable to migrate my VM's because of this problem.

Cheers

Comment: Do you see errors in the logs? It sounds like instances fail to start, so it keeps trying to create new ones.

Comment: I've checked the log files and everything seems to be alright. I found the target_utilization param was responsible for the problem. I removed it and it works fine now.

Comment: how long does an infinite amount of instances take to create, out of interest? :P

Comment: It took a minimum of 5-10 minutes just to get him up to 6 instances. Took quite a while :)

Comment: Another way you can prevent infinite resource creation would be to specify 'max_num_instances' in app.yaml as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#automatic_scaling. 
A question for you: After you removed target_utilization how many instances does your application contain in steady state?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It contains 1 instance, exactly the min_number flag I've configured in my config file.